# React Route definition

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What's the difference between this two lines of code:

1. `<Route exact path="/"><Home/></Route>`
2. `<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />`

Does it do the same work?

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the source, practically, yes.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/42933fe141819e4662113ab2c320bf86be3490fb/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L46-L73)

Answer (score -1):

I think the first is wrong, or maybe it works the same, but it's not the correct way to declare a new route, because it is necessary to bind declare a component inside the declaration of the new route